# How to get Pair Contract Address or LP Pool Address of a Token in web3.py

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, bsc, binance-smart-chain

I managed  to have this code run after few hours of searches but unfortunately, this does not produce the output I wanted. Any ideas what could be the problem?

```
from web3 import Web3
from eth_abi.packed import encode_abi_packed
from eth_abi import encode_abi
import eth_abi

"""
Contract: 0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371
BIN/BNB Address: 0xe432afB7283A08Be24E9038C30CA6336A7cC8218
BIN/BNB LP URL: https://bscscan.com/token/0xe432afB7283A08Be24E9038C30CA6336A7cC8218#balances
"""

CONTRACTS = {"CONTRACT": "0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371",}

PANCAKE_SWAP_FACTORY = "0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73"
PANCAKE_SWAP_ROUTER  = "0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E"
WBNB_ADDRESS = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"

hexadem_= '0x96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f'
factory = PANCAKE_SWAP_FACTORY
abiEncoded_1 = encode_abi_packed(['address', 'address'], (CONTRACTS['CONTRACT'], WBNB_ADDRESS))
salt_ = Web3.solidityKeccak(['bytes'], ['0x' +abiEncoded_1.hex()])
abiEncoded_2 = encode_abi_packed([ 'address', 'bytes32'], ( factory, salt_))
resPair = Web3.solidityKeccak(['bytes','bytes'], ['0xff' + abiEncoded_2.hex(), hexadem_])[12:]

# resPair is the address for the pancakeswap CONTRACT /WBNB pair
print("Token Contract: ", CONTRACTS)
print("BNB-LP Address: ", resPair.hex())    #-- expecting to get  0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371
```

Current Output:

```
BNB-LP Address:  0xde173b8a63b9641a531de0fbb1c5c9eee3b4bc0c
```

Expected Output:

```
Token Contract:  0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371
BNB-LP Address:  0xe432afB7283A08Be24E9038C30CA6336A7cC8218   #-- correct LP Address
```